# SQL - How to return min and max values for each quintile

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In my query I am selecting the current balances of loans. I also created a column that returns which quintile each loan balance falls into.

I used this statement

```
NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY CurrLoanBal)
```

From here, how do I return the min and max values for each quintile? I don't want to group any rows, I want each row to show the min and max for that particular quintile.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50d40/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use aggregate functions and partitioning

```
select s.col1, s.col2, ... s.colN, 
max(s.col1) over (partition by s.col2, ... ),
min(s.col1) over (partition by s.col2, ... )
from stuff as s;
```

where your partition by clause decides how the data is partitioned ("grouped") without grouping it the same way a group by would. This way the window functions are applied to each partition to give you the data you want.

The columns in the partition by bit determine how the rows are partitioned (what separates one quintile from another in your case).

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx for more information.

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I wanted.